# OpenGL: Passing a texture that has the external format GL_RED but the internal format GL_RGBA

Tags: opengl

So I have a texture that has the external format `GL_RED`, and the internal format `GL_RGBA`.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bitmap->width, bitmap->height, 0, layout, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmap->data);
```

I would like to have the textured stored as `(1,1,1,r)` instead of `(r,0,0,0)`.
I wouldn't like to recompute the entire bitmap as an `RGBA` one, and I don't want to create a new shader. Is it possible to tell OpenGL how to interpret the uploaded data?

Comment: Textures do not have an "external format". The `format` parameter specifies the format of the data you're uploading; it doesn't stick with the texture itself. Only the internal format sticks with the texture.

Comment: I know, I was trying to refer to the format I pass the data in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid such divergences between internal format and the data you pass. If you want your texture to have a single color channel that is a normalized, unsigned byte, the correct way to spell that is with `GL_R8` as the internal format. The texture will be stored as a single value of red, with the other channels getting filled in at texture access time with 0, 0, 1 in that order.

You can modify how texture data is accessed with the [texture swizzle setting](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Swizzle). This is a per-texture setting. If you want to receive the data in the shader as `(1, 1, 1, r)`, you can do that with this swizzle setting:

```
GLint swizzleMask[] = {GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_RED};
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA, swizzleMask);
```

Note that thos doesn't change how the data is "stored"; the texture will always be a single-channel, 8-bit unsigned normalized texture. It affects how the shader accesses the texture's data.

Note that you could do this within the shader itself, but really, it's easier to employ a swizzle mask.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was look for! Thanks, and sorry if the question was asked in a confusing way.

Comment: I tried to pass in a mask as a uniform actually, but this is a way better solution

Comment: One more question though: according to glcorearb.h, it requires 3.3. Is that the case? Is it available via extension queries?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `GL_RED` for the internal format.

When you sample the texture in the shader, fill the rest of components (GBA, no R) with the value you wish.

Comment: That requries an extra shader. I want my shader to work with RGBA _and_ RED

Comment: glUseProgram() is costly. I'm trying to use AZDO OpenGL, I want to use as few state switches as possible

Comment: @MattMatt2000 Oh! You didn't talk about using different texture types in the same shader. Then Nico Bolas's answer is better.

Comment: Thank you though ;), I realize the question was phrased in a weird way... Was kinda hard to phrase the problem to begin with